# having problem with the delete table function from a table

Tags: c

Im new and still in the learning process, I tried to find answers on Youtube but it doesn't cut it... I'm TOTALLY out of luck when it comes to people I can ask personally so please help me out please...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_TABLES 6
#define TABLE_PRICE 1000

// Define a structure for table reservations
typedef struct {
    int table_num;
    char booker_name[9];
    char booking_time[7];
    int hours_booked;
    int total_price;
} Reservation;

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    char decision;
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t=========================");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t|Welcome to JJJ Cuisine!|");
    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t|  <3  <3  <3  <3  <3   |\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t|Press enter to continue|\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t=========================\n\n");
    getchar(); // read the enter key
    choices(); // proceed to choices function
    return 0;
}


void choices()
{
    int decision;
    printf("\n\nPlease choose an action: ");
    printf("\n1.) Book a table\n2.) Display Tables\n3.) Remove Booked Table\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &decision);
    switch(decision)
    {
    case 1:
        book_table();
        break;
    case 2:
        display_table();
        break;
    case 3:
        delete_table();
        break;
    default:
        main();
        break;
    }
}

void book_table()
{
    Reservation res;
    int table_exists = 0, i;
    int table_num_input;

    // Open the data file for reading
    FILE *file = fopen("data_table.txt", "r");
    system("cls");
    printf("\nEnter table number (1 to %d): ", MAX_TABLES);
    while (scanf("%d", &table_num_input) != 1)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input. Please enter a number from 1 to %d.\n\n", MAX_TABLES);
        // Clear the input buffer
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    }

    // Check if table number is within the valid range
    if (table_num_input < 1 || table_num_input > MAX_TABLES)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input. Please enter a number from 1 to %d.\n\n", MAX_TABLES);
        book_table();
        return;
    }

    // Check if table number is already booked
    file = fopen("data_table.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(file, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d", &res.table_num, res.booker_name, res.booking_time, &res.hours_booked, &res.total_price) != EOF)
    {
        if (res.table_num == table_num_input)
        {
            table_exists = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    if (table_exists)
    {
        int decision;
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\nTable %d is already booked. Please choose another table.\n\n", table_num_input);
        printf("\nPress [1] to view table schedule\nPress [2] to Proceed booking a table\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &decision);
        // Check if decision is within the valid range
        if (decision < 1 || decision > 2)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid input. Please enter a number from 1 to 2.\n");
            book_table();
            return;
        }
        switch(decision)
        {
        case 1:
            peek();
            book_table();
        case 2:
            book_table();
            break;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        res.table_num = table_num_input;
        printf("\nEnter booker name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", res.booker_name);
        printf("\nEnter booking time: ");
        scanf("%s", res.booking_time);
        printf("\nEnter how many hours the table will be used: ");
        scanf("%d", &res.hours_booked);

        // Calculate the total price
        res.total_price = res.hours_booked * TABLE_PRICE;

        // Save the reservation data to the file
        file = fopen("data_table.txt", "a");
        fprintf(file, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", res.table_num, res.booker_name, res.booking_time, res.hours_booked, res.total_price);
        fclose(file);

        printf("\nTable %d has been successfully reserved for %d hours by %s at %s.\n\n", res.table_num, res.hours_booked, res.booker_name, res.booking_time);
        printf("\n=========================================================================\n");
        printf("Press enter to continue");
        getchar(); // read the enter key

        // Display the updated table
        display_table();
    }
}


void delete_table()
{
    int table_num_input, found = 0;
    Reservation res;
    // Open the data file for reading
    FILE *file = fopen("data_table.txt", "r");

    // Open a temporary file for writing
    FILE *temp_file = fopen("temp_data_table.txt", "w");

    printf("\nEnter table number to delete (1 to %d): ", MAX_TABLES);
    scanf("%d", &table_num_input);

    // Consume remaining characters in the input buffer
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    // Check if table number exists and is within the valid range
    if (table_num_input < 1 || table_num_input > MAX_TABLES)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid input. Please enter a number from 1 to %d.\n\n", MAX_TABLES);
        delete_table();
    }

    // Check if table number exists
    while (fscanf(file, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d", &res.table_num, res.booker_name, res.booking_time, &res.hours_booked, &res.total_price) != EOF)
    {
        if (res.table_num == table_num_input)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("\nTable %d reserved by %s at %s for %d hours has been successfully deleted.\n\n", res.table_num, res.booker_name, res.booking_time, res.hours_booked);
            continue;
        }
        // Write the reservation data to the temporary file
        fprintf(temp_file, "%d,%s,%s,%d,%d\n", res.table_num, res.booker_name, res.booking_time, res.hours_booked, res.total_price);
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(temp_file);


    // Replace the data file with the temporary file
    remove("data_table.txt");
    rename("temp_data_table.txt", "data_table.txt");

    if (!found)
    {
        printf("\nTable %d not found. Please try again.\n", table_num_input);
        choices();
    }
    else
    {
        // Reopen the file for reading
        file = fopen("data_table.txt", "r");

        // Display the updated table data
        display_table(file);

        fclose(file);

        // Return to choices function
        choices();
    }
}

void display_table()
{
    Reservation res;

    // Open the data file for reading
    FILE *file = fopen("data_table.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening data file.\n");
        return;
    }
    // Print all tables in the data file
    printf("\n=========================================================================\n");
    printf("\n\nTable\tBooker Name\t\tBooking Time\tHours Booked\tTotal Price\n\n");
    char line[100];
    int printed_tables[MAX_TABLES] = {0};
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d", &res.table_num, res.booker_name, res.booking_time, &res.hours_booked, &res.total_price);
        if (!printed_tables[res.table_num-1]) {
            printf("%d\t%s\t\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\n\n", res.table_num, res.booker_name, res.booking_time, res.hours_booked, res.total_price);
            printed_tables[res.table_num-1] = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("=========================================================================\n");
    fclose(file);
    // Return to choices function
    choices();
}


void peek()
{
    Reservation res;
    // Open the data file for reading
    FILE *file = fopen("data_table.txt", "r");
    system("cls");
    // Print all tables in the data file
    printf("\n=========================================================================\n");
    printf("\n\nTable\tBooker Name\tBooking Time\tHours Booked\tTotal Price\n\n");
    while (fscanf(file, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d", &res.table_num, res.booker_name, res.booking_time, &res.hours_booked, &res.total_price) != EOF) {
        printf("%d\t%s\t\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\n\n", res.table_num, res.booker_name, res.booking_time, res.hours_booked, res.total_price);
    }
    printf("=========================================================================\n\n");
    fclose(file);
    return;
}
```

, please help me out...

my problem is when i delete a table reservation, it does do the job on the first try, after the 1st deletion process the table will be displayed, but when I try to delete another table, the textfile does not update and the table reservation is still there. id appreciate any help here, hard or soft, Critisizm or Guidance. Im more than welcome to accept any suggestions as well as long as I have something to learn from it.

i was expecting to delete a table reservation, and then prompt the user wether to delete another table or stop, but the problem is when i delete another table after deleting the data_table.txt stops updating the changes.

Comment: OT: If you don't use a variable in a function, then why define it to begin with? Also always declare functions before you use them, otherwise the compiler will not  be able to give you enough errors or warnings if you use them wrongly. And a declaration like `void choices();` tell the compiler that you don't know the arguments for the function, if you want a function to take no arguments you must use `void`, as in `void choices(void)`. Lastly, while it's allowed in C, don't call `main`. It's a bad habit. Use *loops* instead.

Comment: In case of an error in user input, you call your `delete_table` and `book_table` recursively. But what do you expect to happen if that function returns? You will continue right after the recursive call. That will mess up everything. You must avoid to execute the function after returning. Generally, do not use recursion if you don't really need. Use loops instead

Comment: hello sir, thanks for the answer, 
what do you mean when you said " what do you expect to happen if that function returns? " , I feel like I'm about to learn something in this line.

Comment: OK, I realized that you do not return from `delete_table`. And in `book_table` you return also if you called recursively. That's not an issue then, but honestly terrible design. And depending on your environment, you might overflow your stack with this unlimited calling depth. You also open files multiple times without closing. Get rid of your recursion.

Comment: thank you for your feedback.. i will try to improve my code and avoid recursion. thank you very much